# Is heterogeneous array possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, containers

An integer can be stored in a character array and character can be stored in integer array. Does this imply that an array can be heterogeneous data type?

I know that in a container the items must have something in common, but still, can a container have variable something common when explicit conversion takes place?

Comment: No, just because `int` and `char` can be converted between each other (which for `int` to `char` conversion may mean truncation and loss of original value) doesn't mean you store different data types in the array. An array of `char` is still an array of `char` elements *only*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard containers are designed to have all the elements of the same type. There are however several techniques to give the impression of some degree of heterogeneity:

- use a type that can contain all the intended types you mean to store (e.g. `long long` can store also `long`, `int`, `short` and `signed char` values).
- use a `union` type, that has one member of each of the type you intend to store
- use a [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/any.html)
- use a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/variant.html#variant.abstract), which is a better alternative to the union mentioned above.

You could also consider usign a polymorphic type to store objects of any of its derived type. However this could be more tricky as it appears, due to the risk of [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: For an example of a union type (sum type), see `std::`/`boost::variant`.

Comment: @GManNickG can you explain a bit about boost::any

Comment: `boost::any` is probably not what you want, you can think of it like a fancy `void*` - it holds some value, but unless you know what type it is you can't do anything with it. By contrast a tagged union (`boost::variant`) does know what type it holds, and you can apply a generic function to the value without actually having to extract it yourself ("visiting").

Answer (score 1):

In statically typed languages an array must be of homogeneous types.
Saying that “integer types can be stored in char arrays and viceversa” it’s obviously true because **characters are integers** (even if with less bytes), and under some limits `char`s and `int`s are interchangeable.

You may create a class `GenericValue` and subclass it to create an array of heterogeneous values with polymorphism in some way.

But what’s the point? There’s no useful and comfortable way to use those values of different types in C++, and there are not many context it is worth the while to use them in.

Comment: "But what’s the point? There’s no useful and comfortable way to use those values of different types." Have you ever used a variant type? These are quite normal and very useful.

Comment: They’re not that easy and fast to use as they “break” the logic of statically types languages. It is always best practice to keep well-defined types, let’s not diverge into dynamically typed languages.

Comment: So, your argument is "I don't know, FUD"? Do you realize that Haskell *loves* variants (sum types)? Don't let them know they're breaking the logic of statically typed languages!

Comment: I’m not saying they can’t be useful sometimes, but it’s the same as using void pointers. And we’re talking about C++, not Haskell. And my argument is “let’s say you have to loop the array, what can you ever do with the values?” they may be useful but it is rare.

Comment: To be more concrete, any parser (e.g., as part of a compiler) you've ever used has a tree of variant types as its core data structure. My point is your answer is living in a world where these things don't exist, but they do and they're quite useful.

Comment: @GManNickG I’m programming a compiler, and the Abstract Syntax Tree you’re talking about uses class polymorphism. There’s a sort of correlation between classes which is the superclass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156285/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-osnapitzkindle).